# fronze graph import error when using slim.batchnorm in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

When import graph with slim BN layers, errors like `ValueError: graph_def is invalid at node 'conv3_1/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg': Input tensor 'conv3_1/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0' Cannot convert a tensor of type float32 to an input of type float32_ref.` always occurs.

There are some discussion at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3628, but they simply didn't work for me.
Is there any better solution (or workaround)?

Comment: This sounds like something that could be improved about freezing graphs in Tensorflow. I think the right thing to do is to continue the discussion on that github issue.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The right thing to do is to improve this in TF, not get a workaround.